# Why doesn't my code draw the Feynman diagram?

Tags: tikz-styles, feynman

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
  a -- [photon] b,
  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The above is my code. The program stops at `\usepackage{tikz}`. What's the problem here?

Comment: you need to put `\usepackage{tikz}` before `\begin{document}` and presumably also load the `tikz-feynman` package.

Comment: latex doesn't just "stop" it shows the line with `\usepackage` and shows the error message `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.` which by latex standards is fairly accurate message.

Comment: @marmot I did that, now I get a different error. Undefined control sequence \feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b] {

Comment: As @marmot said (and the answer states), you need `tikz-feynman`.

Answer (score 3):

Packages can only be loaded in the preamble, *i.e.* all lines with `\usepackage` must be *before* `\begin{document}`.

In your case, `\usepackage{tikz}` should thus be with the other `\usepackage`s. Furthermore, since you want to draw a Feynman diagram, you should load the `tikz-feynman` package instead of plain `tikz`, since otherwise the `\feynmandiagram` command is not defined. Also, a semicolon needs to be added after `\feynmandiagram`.

With these three things changed, your code becomes:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
  a -- [photon] b,
  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: when I run this the code stops at l. 16 \end{tikzpicture} followed by ? . do you know how to fix this?

Comment: When LaTeX gives errors, you can just press enter repeatedly to still finish compiling the document. The error is given because a semicolon was missing, this is fixed now in the answer above.